# Gorm Go - Query with an empty slice of primary keys

Tags: go-gorm

The Gorm documentation for [Struct & Map Conditions](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Struct-amp-Map-Conditions) provides the following snippet for querying a table with a slice of primary keys

```golang
// Slice of primary keys
db.Where([]int64{20, 21, 22}).Find(&users)
// SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (20, 21, 22);
```

However, if the slice is empty then all records are returned. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/33bc56cbb5916173c670d28fb7fcf6a2bbd0b185/finisher_api.go#L157) for the `Find` function I can see conditions are only added if `len(conds) > 0`

```golang
// Find find records that match given conditions
func (db *DB) Find(dest interface{}, conds ...interface{}) (tx *DB) {
    tx = db.getInstance()
    if len(conds) > 0 {
        if exprs := tx.Statement.BuildCondition(conds[0], conds[1:]...); len(exprs) > 0 {
            tx.Statement.AddClause(clause.Where{Exprs: exprs})
        }
    }
    tx.Statement.Dest = dest
    return tx.callbacks.Query().Execute(tx)
}
```

This is the opposite of what my SQLite command line returns. If the condition is empty then no records are returned (because they all have a primary key)

```sql
-- no records returned
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN ();
```

**Question**

- Is there a way to query a slice of primary keys using Gorm such that if the slice is empty, no records are returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since primary keys increases from `1`, `0` id could be used in a empty query.

```golang
ids := []int64{20, 21, 22}
db.Where(append([]int64{0}, ids...)).Find(&users)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting this but it feels very unintuitive, so I've raised a feature request on go-gorm: https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4857